# Create a click event in the middle of a element/canvas element?

Tags: javascript

I've seen and used code that allows you to create a click event on a element, but it seems these click events are created at the 0,0 coordinates of the element. I have a canvas element that I need a click event created for near the center of it.

How can I create a click event near the center of an element?

For example say I wanted to click on the spot at 20px,30px of this element:

```
<canvas style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
```

I've tried setting the mouse event properties clientX and clientY, but that didn't register the click where it should've so I guess those properties don't do what I thought they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by checking the documentation for `MouseEvent` on MDN, you could try the following.  I did not see a way to select the pixels in the element itself, but you could calculate the position you want on the window using the results of the `getBoundingClientRect` method on your canvas element.

```
var canvasBCR = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {clientX: canvasBCR.left + 20, clientY: canvasBCR.top + 30}));
```

Comment: Hurray! Excellent solution. Threw me for a loop for a second, its .left and .top instead of .x .y. I woulda easily made the same typo. Thanks so much!

Comment: I initially wrote left and top, but saw x and y were options as well.  Maybe that's not as widely supported, will edit.